# How to extract separate text nodes with Jsoup?

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have an element like this :

```
<td> TextA <br/> TextB </td>
```

How can I extract TextA and TextB separately?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Several ways. That really depends on the document itself and whether the given HTML markup is consistent or not. In this particular example you could get the `td`'s child nodes by [`Element#childNodes()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#childNodes%28%29) and then test every node individually if it's a [`TextNode`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.html) or not.

E.g.

```
Element td = getItSomehow();

for (Node child : td.childNodes()) {
    if (child instanceof TextNode) {
        System.out.println(((TextNode) child).text());
    }
}
```

which results in

```
 TextA 
 TextB
```

I think it would be nice if Jsoup offered a `Element#textNodes()` or something to get the child text nodes like as `Element#children()` does to get the child elements (which would have returned the `<br />` element in your example).

Comment: I've implemented Element#textNodes() for 1.6.2, thanks for the suggestion. https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/commit/7b9f17760049161b775fd23b15653961620e259d

Comment: @JonathanHedley You're a life saver! I can't thank you enough for your hard work. Your code and comments are perfect and have saved me hours of Google and StackOverflow.