# Get the source code of a URL

Tags: java, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I need to get the source code of the particular URL using a java code. I was able to get the source code for UTF-8 encoded web page but was not able to get the code for ISO-8859-1 encoded character set. My question, is it possible to get the source code of website with iso-8859-1 using a java program? Please help

Comment: Show us your code. Probably you are using your default system encoding and the `ISO` encoding must be specified explicitly somewhere.

Comment: What was the code you used for getting utf-8 page and where does it fail for the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reading by using following method you need to Specify character set explicitly by

```
    URL url = new URL(URL_TO_READ);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(),"ISO-8859-1" ));
```

How ever if there is little parsing include with your requirement I would suggest you to use [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org) and it will read the character-set from the response of server, Also you could [explicitly set the charset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703434/jsoup-character-encoding-issue)