# Java servlet symbol error

Tags: java, servlets, character-encoding

I'm trying to parse a website and print it again.
But some characters are missing(◄ and ë for example).

Servlet code:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://website.com").get();

    writer.write(document.toString());
    writer.close();
}
```

Error symbol that shows up instead of the character ë:

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703434/jsoup-character-encoding-issue ?

Comment: @superbob fixed 3 symbols but there is still one with the question mark.
Thanks

Comment: What charset did you try ? ISO-8859-1 ? UTF-8 ? The question marks indicates that there are still some chars that aren't properly decoded.