# How to set data encoding read by Jsoup?

Tags: java, character-encoding, jsoup, big5

I try to use post data in [Big5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big5) and get the like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="zh-TW">
```

The java statement is like:

```
Document docs = Jsoup.connect(param)
                     .timeout(30000)
                     .postDataCharset("Big5")
                     .data("syear","104")
                     .data("smonth","6")
                     .data("sday","30")
                     .data("eyear","104")
                     .data("emonth","7")
                     .data("eday","17")
                     .data("SectNO", "不限科別")
                     .data("EmpNO", "不限醫生")
                     .post();
```

How to set charset for sending data to get response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSoup character encoding issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703434/jsoup-character-encoding-issue)

Answer (score 0):

#### Explication

As of Jsoup 1.8.3, `postDataCharset()` sets the charset of data **posted**. This charset isn't reused when it comes to parse the data **read**.

Instead, Jsoup tries to find somehow a meta http-equiv specifying the charset. If it can't find, it assumes by default that the charset is UTF-8. In your case, this assumption is wrong.

#### Workaround

To workaround this, don't let Jsoup *guess* the data encoding for you. Here is how to do it:

```
// Let Jsoup fetch the data
Response res = Jsoup.connect(param)         //
                 .timeout(30000)            //
                 .postDataCharset("Big5")   //
                 .data("syear", "104")      //
                 .data("smonth", "6")       //
                 .data("sday", "30")        //
                 .data("eyear", "104")      //
                 .data("emonth", "7")       //
                 .data("eday", "17")        //
                 .data("SectNO", "不限科別") //
                 .data("EmpNO", "不限醫生")  //
                 .execute();

// Now, we tell it explicitly which encoding to use
Document docs = Jsoup.parse(
                 new String(res.bodyAsBytes(), "Big5"), //
                 param //
);
```