# Append right to left string to a Document in Java

Tags: append, jsoup, document, right-to-left, appendchild

I parse a HTML page to Document with Jsoup at "doc" variable. When I append a right to left string in Persian (سلام) to one of tags it appear as question marks. [ ?????? ]

How can I fix this problem?

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url);
doc.getElementById("id_0").append("<p>سلام</p>");
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703434/jsoup-character-encoding-issue

Comment: Persian is also UTF-8 same as default Jsoup charset. so what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe the browser you're viewing the page in has the wrong encoding?

Comment: No -- my browser encoding is also UTF-8

Comment: where does it appear as question marks?

Comment: Have you tried setting the charset explicitly? take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703434/jsoup-character-encoding-issue).

Comment: yesI tried setting the charset explicitly

Comment: Update your question with what you've already tried.