# Jsoup returns hieroglyphics for cyrillic text

Tags: android, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I am getting tv schedule  from tv program website but I am getting hieroglyphics for text.

This is html

```html
<div id="tabs-1">
<div class="tab-content clear">
 <div class="col">
  <h2 class="col-heading">претпладне</h2>
  <ul class="col-list">
   <li class="col-item">          
    <span class="time">06:45</span>
    <span class="title">
    <span class="h4">Македонија наутро</span>
    <br />
    <span class="em">инфостудио</span>
    </span>
   </li>
   <li class="col-item">          
    <span class="time">09:15</span>
    <span class="title">
    <span class="h4">Музичко интермецо</span>
    <br />
    <span class="em">•</span>
    </span>
   </li>
```

This is what jsoup returns

```html
<li class="col-item">
 b <span class="time">06:45</span>
 <span class="title">
  <span class="h4">ÐÐ°ÐºÐµÐ´Ð¾Ð½Ð¸ÑÐ° Ð½Ð°ÑÑÑÐ¾</span>
  <br>
  <span class="em">Ð¸Ð½ÑÐ¾ÑÑÑÐ´Ð¸Ð¾</span>
 </span>
</li>
<li class="col-item">
 b <span class="time">09:15</span>
 <span class="title">
  <span class="h4">ÐÑÐ·Ð¸ÑÐºÐ¾ Ð¸Ð½ÑÐµÑÐ¼ÐµÑÐ¾</span>
  <br>
  <span class="em">â¢</span>
 </span>
</li>
```

See that ÐÐ°ÐºÐµÐ´Ð¾Ð½Ð¸ÑÐ° Ð½Ð°ÑÑÑÐ¾ thing, thats the problem.
This is my code

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);

Element description = document.getElementById("tabs-1");
Elements c = description.getElementsByTag("li").prepend("b");
Elements time = description.getElementsByClass("time");
Elements title = description.getElementsByClass("title");

String v = c.toString();
adress.append(v);
```

I am using Volley library thats why I am parsing responce string,don't get confused.  This is url I am trying to parse http://creativa5.com/dev/mtvepg/programa/.

I tried using

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(response, "ISO-8859-1");
```

but same thing.

Any help how to encode this to utf-8 ?

Comment: what about change ISO-8859-1 to  utf-8

Comment: Maybe it's problem of database. database is not suppot utf-8. Try ask some one manage database.

Comment: I think the problem is not in the Jsoup but in the response String. print response and check is it appeared correctly. I have copied your html and use your code it's showing me the correct output

Comment: @AshrafulIslam Try copying url I am trying to parse and tell me what you get ?

Comment: @tinysunlight tried utf-8 same thing ,

Comment: Didi you check your database?

Comment: @tinysunlight I am not storing extracted data in database, and if you mean about website is not mine so I can't check that.

But I am pretty sure this is encoding problem, I just don't know how to encode properly with jsoup.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703434/jsoup-character-encoding-issue). Try something like this, as described in the answer. `Document document = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "ISO-8859-1", url);`.

Comment: oh. if you are using volley .Plz provide your Request.Class .

Comment: Maybe I know what's the problem .

Comment: In the request  return you new String(respense) . you should add utf-8 there.

Comment: I have added my code . I have never  used jsoup . But I use volley.

Comment: @phlosopher_mk it's showing me this `<li class="col-item">b <span class="time">06:45</span> <span class="title"> <span class="h4">Македонија наутро</span> <br> <span class="em">инфостудио</span> </span> </li>`  type of content 45 times

Answer (score 0):

```
public class JsonObjectRequestGet extends Request {
    @Override
    protected Response parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            //here to utf-8
            String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));

            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I am using volley ,but I am requesting string because jsoup. I am parsing html not reading json data. I updated the question with my request method .

Comment: Ok, I just tried same thing without volley (just simple Async) and problem was not there . Volley is the problem like you said, can you tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: which jar should i complie if i want to use jsoup.

Comment: compile files('libs/jsoup.jar')  , or downoad jar file from here http://jsoup.org/download

Comment: I fixed the problem by adding newStr = URLDecoder.decode(URLEncoder.encode(response.toString(), "iso8859-1"), "UTF-8"); in response . Than I am parsing newStr . But there is  only one problem , my textview scrolls to the end automatically when data is parsed. How to stop that ?

Comment: Textview scroll when append().Can you upload you layout?

Comment: The problem was that text was selectable , I removed selectable tag. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my request method

```
 private StringRequest mtvPrograma() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://creativa5.com/dev/mtvepg/programa/",
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {




                    Document document = Jsoup.parse(response,"utf-8");


                    Element description = document.getElementById("tabs-1");
                    Elements c = description.getElementsByTag("li").prepend("b");
                    Elements time = description.getElementsByClass("time");
                    Elements title = description.getElementsByClass("title");

                    String v = c.text().replaceAll("b", "\n\n");;

                    adress.append(v);




                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }

    );
    return stringRequest;

}
```

Comment: @tinysunlight for some reason I can't edit question, here is my request method.