# Symbols show up as � after i parse an html webpage using jsoup and display contents in android listview

Tags: android, encoding, jsoup

I would like to understand this problem i have been having.
Im parsing an html source page and displaying the content i want  in a list view in android.
I parse the page using this command.

```
  doc = Jsoup.connect(myURL).get();
```

Symbols such as é or “ ” show up as �.
I understand they are not being recognized by the encoding mechanism but is it because of jsoup or android?
Android default encoding im using is Utf-8 should it not support that?
If it should not how and what should i change it to?
Thank you for you help.

Comment: It has something to do with ASCII caracters shown in UTF8 or the other way around.

Comment: Please, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7716688/5885018

Answer (score 0):

é in ISO-8859-1 (extend ASCII) is the value 233 but in UTF-8 it is the value 195 folowed by 169.

You need to know in what encoding the caracters are saved in because only the values are saved and then interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the help.
making the jsoup call like this :

```
 Document document = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "ISO-8859-1", url);
```

was the way to go i then had to find out the real encoding of the webpage in chrome you can find it in 'more tools' and in my case it was
windowns-1252. One line of code solved the problem:

```
 doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "windows-1252", url);
```