# Jsoup is encoding ISO-8859-1 text thats on a webpage to another encoding

Tags: jsoup

The text is coming from a webpage and it is already in `ISO-8859-1`;

First let me show you an example of the problem. Let us say that this one of the pieces of text from the webpage, `Mark Helström`. When I  use `Jsoup` to parse the page, that piece of text will then turn into: `Mark HelstrÃÂ¶m`

Here is an example of the webpage code:

```
<body>
    <p>Mark HelstrÃÂ¶m</p>
</body>
```

Here is the code where I parse the webpage:

```
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/translator/test";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    System.out.println("charset=" + doc.outputSettings().charset());

    doc.outputSettings().charset(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));

    System.out.println("charset=" + doc.outputSettings().charset());

    for(Element code : doc.select("*")) {
        System.out.println("code=" + code.ownText());               
    }
```

Here is the output generated by the code above:

```
charset=ISO-8859-1
charset=ISO-8859-1
code=
code=
code=
code=
code=Mark HelstrÃÂ¶m
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSoup character encoding issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703434/jsoup-character-encoding-issue)

Comment: Not a possible duplicate. I tried that method and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show your code where you tried to parse the content as ISO-8859-1? What you have currently is the output charset, not the input.

Comment: @ZackTeater I updated my question so that it contains your solution.

Comment: could you update the sample html? seems to be missing 5 paragraphs.  It could be the ownText() method, which only displays the element's text node.  If there is an embedded element, it won't display it.  Such as, <p><b>foo</b></p> .  Can you try with text() instead?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine when I parse this page for the characters.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38875180/jsoup-is-encoding-iso-8859-1-text-thats-on-a-webpage-to-another-encoding")
            .get();

    System.out.println("charset=" + doc.outputSettings().charset());

    doc.outputSettings().charset(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));

    System.out.println("charset=" + doc.outputSettings().charset());

    for (Element code : doc.select(".post-text p code:contains(mark)"))
        System.out.println("code=" + code.ownText());
```

**Console**

```
charset=UTF-8
charset=ISO-8859-1
code=Mark Helström
code=Mark HelstrÃÂ¶m
```