# Jsoup parse with unreadable characters

Tags: encoding, jsoup

When parsing flashscore server with JSoup I have unreadable characters.
Jsoup code:

```
       document = Jsoup.connect(URL + LABEL + SEASON + 1 + END)
                     .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                     .header("x-fsign", FSIGN)
                     .get();
```

Server response:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  SA÷1¬~ZA÷ИТАЛИЯ: Серия В¬ZEE÷6oug4RRc¬ZB÷98¬ZY÷Италия¬ZC÷GbNgKxPB¬ZD÷p¬ZE÷K28bJgeL
```

How to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

Set the correct charset in the "charset" attribute:
[JSoup character encoding issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703434/jsoup-character-encoding-issue)

```
document = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "ISO-8859-1", url);
```

Comment: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://d.flashscore.ru/x/feed/tr_1_98_6oug4RRc_169_1_3_ru_1

Comment: must connect not parse, for setting headers