# Stuck in Jsoup parsing Html

Tags: java, html, jsoup

how can i get that textA, text B and text C seperately?

i have tried .Owntext buth it gives all of them.I need something that gives text between two unique named h3s.

```
  <div class="Example">
      <h3>A:</h3>
       TextA
      <h3>B:</h3>
       TextB
      <h3>C:</h3>
       TextC
  <\div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you post your code showing what you've tried, people can help you understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract separate text nodes with Jsoup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164376/how-to-extract-separate-text-nodes-with-jsoup)

Comment: h3 elements dont inclued  that texts so selecting ".example h3" with foreach loop of elements and getting ".text" of element doesn't work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177867/jsoup-extracting-text) is almost a perfect answer for your question. It would look about like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);
Element div = doc.select("div").first();

for (Node node : div.childNodes()) {
    if (node instanceof org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode) {
        System.out.println(node.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicer is `if (node instanceof TextNode)`, there's no need to use reflection here.