# Jsoup get text in paragraph and sub tags

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I have an HTML page on which I wish to run "specialised" TTS:

For eg:

```
<h3>Title <u>Page<u> by Ada Lovelace</h3>
```

I want to read title and page in a different way:

When I use:

```
    Element body=doc.body();
    Elements elements= body.select("*");
    for(Element element:elements){
        if(!element.ownText().equals("") && element.hasText()){
            Log.d("Epub",element.tagName()+" "+element.ownText());

        }
    }
```

I get the Log output as:

```
h3 Title by Ada Lovelace

u Page
```

I want to get the data as:

```
h3 Title

u Page

h3 by Ada Lovelace
```

I do not have any access to he HTML files

Any help is appreciated thanks in advance!

**[EDIT]**

Hey So I figured a way to do it but instead of using Jsoup I used XML pull parser

```
private ArrayList<String> stackOfTags=new ArrayList<String>();
private int indexOfTags=-1;

private void prepareTextToSpeech__onHold() {
    String opening_tag="";
    try{
        XmlPullParser parser=prepareText__onHold();
        int eventType=parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            switch (eventType){
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    opening_tag=parser.getName();
                    stackOfTags.add(parser.getName());
                    indexOfTags++;
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    String temp=parser.getText();
                    if(temp.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*") && !opening_tag.equals("script")){
                        contentMap.addItemInMap(opening_tag,parser.getText());
                        Log.d("Epub",stackOfTags.get(indexOfTags)+" "+parser.getText());
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    stackOfTags.remove(indexOfTags);
                    indexOfTags--;
                    break;
            }
            eventType=parser.next();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("Epub",e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

This however only works on well formed HTML. In the event that is not the case can someone help

Comment: You can manipulate html before parsing, for example:  `String html = "<h3>Title <u>Page</u> by Ada Lovelace</h3>";
  html = html.replace("<u>", "</h3><u>").replace("</u>", "</u><h3>");
  Elements elements = Jsoup.parse(html).getAllElements();`

Comment: Hi so the thing is I don't have the html with me its made by some book authors. Thanks for the help though

Comment: The original HTML does not seem to be valid HTML to me. There is no closing tags for the two ```<u>```. Are you sure the original HTML is not something like ```<h3>Title <u>Page</u> by Ada Lovelace</h3>```?

Comment: did any answer solve your problem? If so, please accept the appropriate answer and by that marking the question as solved for others. If you found an answer useful, don't hesitate to upvote for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the original HTML is `<h3>Title <u>Page</u> by Ada Lovelace</h3>`

If this is the case your HTML seems well formatted. Jsoup allows to read the the contents of each TextNode, so you very well can read out "Title", "Page" and "by Ada Lovlace" as different strings.

I don't have a running Java environment with me right now, so I can't provide working code, but here is a pointer to sources that tell you how it is done:

[How to extract separate text nodes with Jsoup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164376/how-to-extract-separate-text-nodes-with-jsoup)

[Jsoup - extracting text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177867/jsoup-extracting-text)

Comment: OK I will give it a shot. There is something with a higher priority that I have to do so I'll look into that later